# Gson error "Not enough information to infer type variable T" when passing the TypeToken

Tags: android, kotlin, gson

I want to deserialize the list of maps that I return from a different activity. Here is my code:

```
val listType = object : TypeToken<List<Map<String, Any>>>() {}.type
val stepsList = Gson().fromJson(resultStr,  listType)
```

`fromJson()` here shows the error "Not enough information to infer type variable T."

I don't understand how this is possible when I literally specify the TypeToken for my object. I tried a couple different methods of getting the list type (including the inline functions) but they all result in the same error. How can I make it work?

Comment: Try to simply specify the type of `stepsList`. Also, I believe it won't work with `Any` anyway as it can't know the type when deserializing.

Comment: @broot, yes, you were right, I copied it from a tutorial and had to change it to String to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the type of the `fromJson` call:

```kotlin
Gson().fromJson<List<Map<String, Any>>>(resultStr, listType)
```

This should fix the error.

Comment: I prefer this one val stepsList: List<Map<String, Any>> = Gson().fromJson(resultStr,  listType) easy to read

Answer (score 0):

Gson has a few `Gson.fromJson(..., Type): T` methods where the `T` is not constrained in any way by the arguments you pass to `fromJson`. Therefore the compiler cannot determine the type of `stepsList` because it can be anything, and you can (and have to) choose it. Often you don't have to explicitly specify the type when the compiler can infer it.

However, this error actually highlights a flaw with the API of Gson: These `fromJson(..., Type)` methods are not type safe, and you as user would not even notice it at compile time, but would only notice it at runtime when you encounter a `ClassCastException`. For example, the following compiles just fine, but it is wrong and fails at runtime:

```kotlin
val listType = object : TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}.type
// Specifies the wrong type here; no warning at compile time
val stepsList: List<DefinitelyNotMyClass> = Gson().fromJson("[{}]",  listType)
// Fails with ClassCastException at runtime
val obj: DefinitelyNotMyClass = stepsList[0]
```

If you are using Gson 2.10 or newer you should prefer the `fromJson(..., TypeToken<T>): T` methods. Here the result type `T` is constrained by the type token parameter, so these methods are type safe. You therefore also don't have to specify the type a second time anymore because the compiler can now infer the type. To use these methods, simply omit the `.type` call for the `TypeToken`:

```kotlin
val listType = object : TypeToken<List<Map<String, Any>>>() {}
val stepsList = Gson().fromJson(resultStr, listType)
```